# facebook post image to user wall and image store in my fan page album

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Isn't possible facebook allow us from my apps post or share image to user wall and then at the same time the user image will store in my fan page album?

And suggestion and opinion how to do it? hopefully you guy able provide some code for me

step1

```
$user       = $facebook->getUser();
$loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
            'scope'  => 'email,publish_stream,user_birthday,user_location,user_work_history,user_about_me,user_hometown,user_photos'
        )
);
```

step2 , 4 ,5

```
 $file='images/'.$_FILES["file"]['name'];
        if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$file))
        {
            $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
            $post_data = array(
            'name'=>$_POST['album'],
            'description'=>$_POST['album']
            );
            $data['album'] = $facebook->api("/me/albums", 'post', $post_data); 
            //$file = $file_name;
            $post_data = array(
            "message" => $_POST['message'],
            "source" => '@' . realpath($file)
            );
            $album_id = $data['album']['id'];
            $data['photo'] = $facebook->api("/$album_id/photos", 'post', $post_data);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possible...steps

1. take user publish stream permissions - scope - publish_stream,user_photos
2. set application for uploading image..setFileUploadSupport(true);
3. send the image to users wall using feed api
4. fetch user photo
5. Upload it on pages' album by albums api

Comment: Hi Madan Koshti, I had follow your step, can you check my code whether similar with your step? and I not really sure how the 3rd step code, can you provide some example code for me? thanks

Comment: $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
                                    array(
                                      'link' => 'www.example.com',
                                      'message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!',
          'picture' => 'http URL to photo'
                                 ));

For additional info:
 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/